# Using local.js to store sails-mysql password

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to use mysql as my database, but I can't figure out how to get my config/adapters.js to use mysql information in config/local.js to connect. What's the correct way to store the connection information so that sails-mysql can connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**config/local.js** is merged on top of all other configuration.  So you can just put your own `adapters` key in there:

```
{
    adapters: {
        default: 'myLocalAdapter',
        myLocalAdapter: {
            module: 'sails-mysql',
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'database'
        }
    }
}
```

and it'll be picked up and used by Sails.

**EDIT** In sails v0.10.x, use the key `connections` instead of `adapters` as the two are now differentiated and connections now hold authentication info.  The original answer was for an earlier version of sails.

Comment: It should be `connections` instead of `adapters` in v0.10.x, no?

Comment: Yes, for v0.10.x, you use `connections`, and set the default connection in your **config/models.js** file as the `connection` key.

Answer (score 0):

As of latest version of sails (i.e 0.12), while writing this answer, there is no `Adapters.js`. The list of connections are specified in the `config/connections.js` and default connection to use for all models are specified under `config/models.js`. So, going by this change the way to override the database configuration for local is specifying as below in `config.local.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    connections: {
        localMongoServer: {
            adapter: 'sails-mongo',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 27017,
            user: 'YOUR_DB_USER',
            password: 'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD',
            database: 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
        }
    },
    models: {
        connection: 'localMongoServer'
    }
}
```

***NOTE***: As in accepted answer, just changing `adapters` to `connections` won't work, since there is no `default` attribute under `connections`.