# Node/Sails/Node-Postgres, best practice for storing connection string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-connection, sails.js

I'm using the Node-Postgres package for querying a postgresql/postgis database for an app I'm building within the Sails.js framework.

I don't know where the best place to store my connection string for the node-postgres package would be to make it accessible in models and controllers but still secure.

For example, if I want to execute a query against the postgres database from within a model, what I currently do:

```
    var conString = "postgres://postgres:mypass@localhost:5432/myapp_dev";
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect();

    var junk = [];
    client.query('SELECT * FROM junk', function (err, result) {
        // Stuff I do with the query result
    });
```

Obviously it's bad practice/inconvenient to declare this connectionstring and new client every time I need to execute a query. So, what I would like to be able to do is:

```
client.connect();
var junk = [];

client.query('SELECT * FROM junk', function (err, result) {
    // Stuff I do with the query result
});
```

So I just removed the conString and new client declarations. But I don't know where in my app to store those to make them accessible yet secure.

My directory structure follows the standard Sails.js application structure, similar to this: http://runnable.com/UlbJJhdpQyoWAAAK/sails-js-example-project-for-node-js-and-webserver

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In sails.js, you can set environment-specific configs in config/env/development.js, or config/env/production.js.

Always store all sensitive info in environment variables, and never in config files. So your config file would read a env variable called `POSTGRES_CONNECTION` like so:

```
process.env.POSTGRES_CONNECTION
```

Comment: This is the more secure mechanism to deal with this sort of thing - certainly. If properly secured the only user that can get to that variable would be the one that could run the process and if that user is compromised, you're already hosed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this same question, I would recommend storing your Sails database adapter definitions in the local.js file.

See the solution here for an example: [Using local.js to store sails-mysql password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460920/using-local-js-to-store-sails-mysql-password)